# SQL Server stored procedure works in SSMS but not as Access pass-through

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pass-through

I am attempting to troubleshoot an issue reported to me by a user. The application in question is an Access front end with a SQL Server back end. In a nutshell, the procedure in question attaches new medical claims to an existing subrogation case.  (For those as unfamiliar with the term as I was, it's where my employer (an insurance company) is disputing with another company which of us is the primary payer and how much each side is to pay, such as when you have both health and auto insurance and get hurt in a car accident.)

Sounds straightforward enough, right? Here's the catch: the stored procedure works perfectly fine when run directly through SSMS. It only fails when this is executed via a pass-through query. Additionally, it even when run through the front end, it works correctly for 99% of our cases.

Here is the stored procedure involved:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AppSchema].[USP_StoredProcWithError] 
    @ContractNum VARCHAR(9), 
    @PatientBirthDate DATE, 
    @PatientFstName VARCHAR(15), 
    @GrpID VARCHAR(9), 
    @CvgStartDate DATE, 
    @CvgEndDate DATE, 
    @FileNumber VARCHAR(15), 
    @SearchStartDate DATE, 
    @SearchEndDate DATE, 
    @AltName NVARCHAR(15) = NULL 
AS 
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ClaimStagingMedical') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #ClaimStagingMedical 

    /* CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE */
    SELECT ClaimID 
    INTO #ClaimStagingMedical 
    FROM DBName.DBSchema.ClaimsTableName CTN WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE YR_MTH >= CAST(YEAR(@CvgStartDate) AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(@CvgStartDate) AS VARCHAR), 2) 
      AND PYMT_DATE BETWEEN @SearchStartDate AND @SearchEndDate 
      AND FST_SERV_DATE BETWEEN @CvgStartDate AND @CvgEndDate 
      AND AUTOGEN_NUM = @ContractNum 
      AND PAT_DOB_DATE = @PatientBirthDate 
      AND GRP_BASE1_NUM+GRP_BASE2_NUM = @GrpID 
      AND (LEFT(LEFT(PATIENT_NAME, (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME) + 1))), 3) = LEFT(@PatientFstName, 3) 
           OR 
           LEFT(LEFT(PATIENT_NAME, (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME) + 1))), 3) = LEFT(@AltName, 3) 
          ) 
      AND LatestICNInd IS NULL

    UNION

    SELECT ClaimID 
    FROM DBName.DBSchema.ClaimsTableName CTN WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE YR_MTH >= CAST(YEAR(@CvgStartDate) AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(@CvgStartDate) AS VARCHAR), 2) 
      AND PYMT_DATE BETWEEN @SearchStartDate AND @SearchEndDate 
      AND FST_SERV_DATE BETWEEN @CvgStartDate AND @CvgEndDate 
      AND SUB_CERT_BASE_NUM = @ContractNum 
      AND PAT_DOB_DATE = @PatientBirthDate 
      AND GRP_BASE1_NUM + GRP_BASE2_NUM = @GrpID 
      AND (LEFT(LEFT(PATIENT_NAME, (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME) + 1))), 3) = LEFT(@PatientFstName, 3)
           OR
           LEFT(LEFT(PATIENT_NAME, (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - (LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME) + 1))), 3) = LEFT(@AltName, 3)
          ) 
      AND LatestICNInd IS NULL

    /* INSERT CLAIM LINES */
    INSERT INTO AppSchema.AppClaimsTable
                          (FileNumber, ClaimID, YR_MTH, ConnectToCase,  NotConnected, 
                           SendForAdjustment, SendWithCheck, Credit, 
                           CLM_ACVN_PLAN_NUM, ICN13,  LINE_SEQUENCE_NUM, 
                           LastModifiedDate, LoadType)
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            @FileNumber AS FileNumber, CTN.ClaimID, CTN.YR_MTH, 
            1 AS ConnectToCase, 0 AS NotConnected, 
            0 AS SendForAdjustment, 0 AS SendWithCheck, 0 AS Credit, 
            CTN.CLM_ACVN_PLAN_NUM, 
            LEFT(CTN.ICN_NUM,13) AS ICN13, 
            CTN.LINE_SEQUENCE_NUM, 
            CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AS LastModifiedDate, 
            'M' As LoadType
        FROM
            DBName.DBSchema.ClaimsTableName CTN WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN
            #ClaimStagingMedical CSM ON CTN.ClaimID = CSM.ClaimID 
        LEFT JOIN   
            (SELECT 
                 FileNumber, 
                 ClaimID 
             FROM 
                 AppSchema.AppClaimsTable WITH (NOLOCK)
             WHERE  
                 FileNumber = @FileNumber) FNLoaded ON CTN.ClaimID = FNLoaded.ClaimID 
        LEFT JOIN   
            (SELECT
                 FileNumber, AdjClaimID 
             FROM   
                 AppSchema.AppClaimsTable WITH (NOLOCK)
             WHERE  
                 FileNumber = @FileNumber) FNLoadedAdj ON CTN.ClaimID = FNLoadedAdj.AdjClaimID 
        WHERE       
            FNLoaded.FileNumber IS NULL
            AND FNLoadedAdj.FileNumber IS NULL

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS RowsAdded;
```

I am fully aware that the LEFT part of the WHERE clause is entirely too complicated and can be replaced just fine with LEFT(PATIENT_NAME, 3), as PATIENT_NAME is saved as 'FirstName MI LastName'.  I already plan on doing just that.

Anyway, the actual pass-through is much simpler:

```
EXEC AppSchema.USP_StoredProcWithError @ContractNum = '123456789', @PatientBirthDate = '1/1/1950', @PatientFstName = 'BOB', @GrpID = '123456789', @CvgStartDate = '1/1/2000', @CvgEndDate = '12/31/9999', @FileNumber = '1234567', @SearchStartDate = '1/1/2000', @SearchEndDate = '12/31/9999'
```

The error being returned by SQL Server is this:
Error Number: 537
Description: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

When I execute the exact same statement directly in SSMS, the procedure runs as intended and does what it is supposed to.  When run in Access as a pass-through, however, I get the above error.

Note that the parameter in question is determined by the USP rather than being passed to the function.  I have checked the data involved, and PATIENT_NAME is always 14 characters in length, and the first name (which the overly complicated LEFT function checks, is at least 3 characters in every instance where this happens.  The case I'm using as my test case has a standard name that the LEFT function parses out exactly as expected.

There are no non-printing characters hidden in the data - I checked.  The field is an nvarchar(31) field, but all the data is 14 characters long, regardless of whether it had to be padded or truncated to reach that length.

I have also tried replacing

```
    ( 
        LEFT(LEFT(PATIENT_NAME,(LEN(PATIENT_NAME)-(LEN(PATIENT_NAME)-CHARINDEX(' ',PATIENT_NAME)+1))),3)=LEFT(@PatientFstName,3)
        OR
        LEFT(LEFT(PATIENT_NAME,(LEN(PATIENT_NAME)-(LEN(PATIENT_NAME)-CHARINDEX(' ',PATIENT_NAME)+1))),3)=LEFT(@AltName,3)
    )
```

with

```
    ( 
        LEFT(PATIENT_NAME,3)=LEFT(@PatientFstName,3)
        OR
        LEFT(PATIENT_NAME,3)=LEFT(@AltName,3)
    )
```

to no avail.  No error is generated by SQL Server, but Access returns 'Pass-through query with ReturnsRecords property set to True did not return any records', which shouldn't happen because of the final SELECT in the USP.  Additionally, there are 265 records that match the criteria in the USP itself with the values I am using as a test case.  Additionally, as with the original, the same EXEC statement that failed in Access runs the procedure without error when executed in SSMS.

I have spent several hours working on this, both now and a year and a half ago, and I have not found an answer.  My previous issue with this is documented [HERE](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=298780).

I would dearly love if someone can point me to why this keeps happening, and why it only happens occasionally.

**ADDENDUM 2019-08-26:**

When I started work this morning, this procedure was now working correctly.  It has GOT to be a data issue someplace, even though I looked for one and didn't find anything.  I do thank everyone for their help, and will be taking into account the suggestions made here when this gets rewritten next year as part of our redesign of this application.

Comment: What if you ditch the LEFT entirely and send the name as 'BOB%', performing a `PATIENT_NAME LIKE @first3ofName`  - have the front end trim the name down to 3 and append a %

Comment: May not be affecting your result set, BUT, first thing in your stored procedure AFTER  the AS statement should be SET NOCOUNT ON. This will ensure you're not getting the row count(s) affected information your front end doesn't expect.

Comment: I would start by getting those NOLOCK hints out of there. That nasty little bugger causes some pretty serious issues from time to time. Things like missing and/or duplicate rows. And a whole list of other nasties too...https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Will the SET NO COUNT ON prevent the results from being reported by the SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS RowsAdded; at the end?  The app uses that to report how many claims were added to the case.

Comment: As to the NOLOCK hints, they were put in because this touches on a 2 billion record claims table, and the app was regularly getting locked out for extended periods by other apps as people went about their business.  I can certainly look into this, however!

Comment: Caius Jard - I'll give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: Caius Jard - I implemented your suggestion (as well as Sean Lange's NOLOCK one), but I received the same results (no records posted when run via Access Passthrough but works perfectly when run directly via SSMS).  :-(

Comment: It's like it's a data error, but I can't find anything in the data that would be causing this to work when run one way but not when the exact same command is passed in from another app.

Comment: The dates should be in the format of: YYYY-MM-DD. Your use of slashes and a different format is a BIG surprise that T-SQL accepts that query as written. So, even running that query above from 100% SSMS without Access likely could  cause issues.  so the date formats should be @PatientBirthDate = '1950-1-1'

Comment: Honestly, Albert, I was surprised by that as well.  I didn't expect it to work the first time I saw that, but SQL Server seems to translate those strings just fine.  As to the non-Access comment, those strings are actually being supplied by Access.  Another front end (and one will be built sometime next year) may supply them in a different way, and if I have any say in the matter, it will be the YYYY-MM-DD format.  Unfortunately, I didn't write the original query, and updating it right now isn't on the table, since it's working with the MM/DD/YYYY dates just fine atm.  :-(

Comment: For the record here, I'd give everyone who posted a potential answer or comment an upvote if I could, but I don't have enough rep yet, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. I stand corrected the given date format works - it still should be in sql ansi format - YYYY-MM-DD, but if what you have works, then it works!!!